# How to make a function that returns an array with dynamic key names for NodeJS?

Tags: arrays, node.js, dynamic, key, sequelize.js

I'm working on a RESTful api built with NodeJS, express, express-resource, and sequelize for MySQL ORM. I want to be able to retrieve a set of records and respond with res.json(records). However, I am unable to directly use the collection returned by sequelize. When I try, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

As a work around, I created a function that takes the records input and returns an array:

```
/**
 * takes an Array of records and 
 * returns a collection
 *
 * @param {Array} recs
 * @return {Array}
 * @api public
 */
function recs2Array(recs){
    for(var c = 0; c < recs.length; c++){
        var collection = [];
        (function(c){
            // this is crap and must be done for every query
            var data = {
                id: recs[c]['id'],
                gender: recs[c]['gender']
            };
            collection.push(data);
            // debugger;
        })(c);
    };
    return collection;
};
```

Now, this is terribly inefficient because I have to manually define all of the array keys that are to be returned. This means I have to use this pattern everywhere I want to res.json() for each model.find() of model.findAll(). In one of my resource controllers I have to do this for multiple collections resulting lots of extra code.

To make this better, I'm trying to create a function that will generate the array keys dynamically:

```
/**
 * takes an Array of records
 * and and Array of fields and returns 
 * a collection.
 *
 * @param {Array} recs
 * @param {Array} fields
 * @return {Array}
 * @api public
 */
function recs2ray(recs, fields){
    for(var c = 0; c < recs.length; c++){
        fields = fields || null;
        var collection = [];
        (function(c){
            for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
                (function(i){
                    // how do I create dynamic,
                    // variable key names?
                })(i);
            }
            debugger;
        }
    };
};
```

Unfortunately, I'm not really sure how to make dynamic array keys. I was thinking that I would pass in a predefined array that contains fields that will be mapped in the function call:

```
var recs = recs2Array(genders, {['id', 'gender']});
```

When I do this I get the feeling am undermining sequelize ORM in some sense. So, My question is, "How can I dynamically map fields from the array that is returned by sequelize's model.findAll() to an array that is pushed to a collection that is returned to the caller?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var input = ...;
var result = input.map(function(row) {
  var result = {};
  ['id', 'gender'].forEach(function(key) {
    result[key] = row[key];
  });
  return result;
});
```

Or if you want to do it with a helper method:

```
function purify(obj, keys) {
  return obj.map(function(row) {
    var result = {};
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      result[key] = row[key];
    });
    return result;
  });
}
var result = purify(..., ['id', 'gender']);
```

Comment: this works! thanks thejh, I should have thought about the good ol .map().